# pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal, pcl::normal> Unresolvable external symbol

Tags: point-cloud-library

I use different configurations of the normal estimation, but some fail:

```
pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> ne;          // work
pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::Normal> ne;       // work
pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal, pcl::Normal> ne; // not work
```

error LNK2001:Unresolvable external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl pcl::NormalEstimation<struct pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal,struct pcl::Normal>::computeFeature(class pcl::PointCloud &)" (? computeFeature@ ? $NormalEstimation@UPointXYZRGBNormal@pcl@@UNormal@2@@pcl@@MEAAXAEAV ? $PointCloud@UNormal@pcl@@@2@@Z)

Comment: What version of PCL are you using? Did you compile it yourself?

Comment: PCL1.11.1, I didn't compile it.

Answer (score 1):

PCL API is based on templates. The most common use cases are instantiated by default (usually done in the *.cpp* files, such as: [normal_3d.cpp](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/features/src/normal_3d.cpp))

`pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal, pcl::Normal>` wasn't instantiated during compilation of the PCL binaries you're using, so you need to do it yourself:

```
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/impl/instantiate.hpp>  // defines the PCL_INSTANTIATE_PRODUCT macro
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#include <pcl/features/impl/normal_3d.hpp> // make sure to include the .hpp file

PCL_INSTANTIATE_PRODUCT(NormalEstimation, ((pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal))((pcl::Normal)))

pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal, pcl::Normal> ne;
```